# 'Float' is not convertible to 'UInt8' in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I receive a type-related error (`'Float' is not convertible to 'UInt8'`) while using the following formula in Swift. Although I've seen posts with similar questions, I can't seem to figure out why, in this case, the conversion to UInt8 is occurring in the first place and how to fix the type conversion error. I'm a newcomer to the language.

```
func compoundInterest (principal p: Float, interestRate r: Float,
    timesCompounded n: Int, years t: Int) -> Float {
        return p * pow(1 + (r / n), n * t)
}

compoundInterest(principal: 150, interestRate: 0.05, timesCompounded: 2, years: 10)
```

Comment: Why are you using Float? Are you deliberately trying to get inaccurate results?

Comment: "I'm a newcomer to the language."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is misleading but the problem is that Swift doesn't do implicit type conversions — just to pull one part of your expression out:

```
r / n
```

`r` is a floating point type. `n` is an integer type. In C the promotion rules would implicitly concert `n` to a float. That doesn't happen in Swift.

You probably want explicitly to cast all your integer types to `Float` to resolve the issue.